# Grails - Spock - excution failed for task ':test' - Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, grails, spock

I am using Grails + groovy with Spock. The application was building fine till I installed Spock and started writing unit test.

JVM version - 1.8.0_171***Grails version - 3.3.6***Groovy version - 2.4.15

Dependencies -

```
testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb:1.1.2"
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-2"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-test-mixins:3.3.0.RC1"
```

I tried "clean" and "Invalidate caches / restart" in IntelliJ(ultimate) too.

[Build failed with an exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMMJL.png)

[Initialization Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaiA1.png)

[unit test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GItry.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a version problem to me. Also, use `ControllerUnitTest` trait instead of test mixin. So start with removing these lines from `build.gradle`.

```
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-2"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-test-mixins:3.3.0.RC1"
```

Then update the test to implement `ControllerUnitTest` trait. [Here](https://github.com/grails-guides/grails-controller-testing/blob/master/complete/src/test/groovy/demo/StudentControllerSpec.groovy) is an example.

You should also check the [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTesting).

Comment: I removed the spock framework dependency and it is building fine now. Thanks!